# Add sequence of interaction terms to linear model, lm()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lm

My data is formatted like this:

```
mpg     disp    c1  c2  c3
21.0    160.0   0   0   0
21.0    160.0   0   0   0
22.8    108.0   1   0   0
21.4    258.0   1   0   0
18.7    360.0   0   1   0
18.1    225.0   1   0   0
```

And I would like to run a linear model like this, where `c1` through to `c3` are all interacted with another explanatory variable, `disp`:

```
lm(mpg ~ disp:c1 
       + disp:c2
       + disp:c3, df)
```

Of course, my real dataset has many more than 3 interactions, but all of the variables I need to interact are sequentially ordered as columns and all sequentially named (eg c1, c2, etc).

Is there an easy way to specify an interaction between `disp` and `c1` through to say `c100`?

Code for reproducing my sample dataset below:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mtcars
df <- df %>% mutate(c = factor(carb))
dummies <- model.matrix(data = df, ~ c + 0)
dummies <- as_data_frame(dummies)
df <- cbind(df, dummies)
df <- df %>% select(mpg, disp, c1:c3)
head(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste` the values in required order and use `formula`

```
lm(formula(paste0("mpg ~ ", paste0("disp:", "c", 1:3, collapse = " + "))), df)

#Call:
#lm(formula = formula(paste0("mpg ~ ", paste0("disp:", "c", 1:3, 
#    collapse = " + "))), data = df)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)      disp:c1      disp:c2      disp:c3  
# 19.7862454    0.0196435    0.0008339   -0.0126405
```

where

```
paste0("mpg ~ ", paste0("disp:", "c", 1:3, collapse = " + ")) #gives
#[1] "mpg ~ disp:c1 + disp:c2 + disp:c3"
```

This gives the same output when you manually apply the function `lm`

```
lm(mpg ~ disp:c1 + disp:c2 + disp:c3, df)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reformulate`

```
lm(reformulate(paste0("disp:", "c", 1:3), "mpg"), df)
#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(paste0("disp:", "c", 1:3), "mpg"), data = df)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)      disp:c1      disp:c2      disp:c3  
# 19.7862454    0.0196435    0.0008339   -0.0126405
```